# Return values of .get() method in for loop - need to change my thinking?

Tags: python, python-2.7, get, return

I am taking an algorithms class on Udacity. I've hit a sticking point in the class where I was not able to solve the problem. Instead I went into the discussion forums to look at other answers for help. However when reading the code I could not figure out how it worked after much trying to do so. Any help GREATLY appreciated

What I am trying to understand is this block of code:

```
graph = [(0, 1), (1, 5)]
def get_degree(graph):
    degree = {}
    for x, y in graph:
        degree[x] = degree.get(x, 0) + 1
        degree[y] = degree.get(y, 0) + 1
    return degree
```

I have looked at the Python docs and watched a couple youtube videos to get an understanding on dictionaries, tuples and the get method. This is where I'm stuck:

```
def get_degree(graph):
    degree = {}
    for x, y in graph:
        print degree
        degree[x] = degree.get(x, 0) + 1
        print x, y
        print degree.get(x, 0) + 1
        print degree[x]
        print degree

        degree[y] = degree.get(y, 0) + 1
        print degree
    return ""

graph = [(0, 1), (1, 5)]

get_degree(graph)
```

When I call this fuction my output is as follows:

```
{}
0 1
2
1
{0: 1}
{0: 1, 1: 1}
{0: 1, 1: 1}
1 5
3
2
{0: 1, 1: 2}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 5: 1}
```

Now he's my process for understanding this:

1. Prints out degree which is an empty dict so it get {}
2. prints out x, y which is the first tuple so i get 0 1

HELP NEEDED HERE* 3. this statement prints out 2 which confuses me because when calling degree.get(x, 0) + 1 I would expect to get a value of 1. The way I see it when it called degree.get(x,0) it should see that the first x is 0 from the first tuple (0, 1) then would return that 0 and add 1 to it giving me a value of 1.

HELP NEEDED HERE* 4. Now I print degree[x] this should be the same value as above because "degree[x] = degree.get(x, 0) + 1" However the output from this print statement is 1

HELP NEEDED HERE* 5. Now I ask it to print the dictionary thus far which I would expect it to be {degree[x]} because at this point I have only supply that, however my output is {0, 1}

If someone can help me think about this correctly I think I could figure the rest out on my own.

Comment: just move the `print degree` below the `degree[x] = degree.get(x, 0) + 1` and you will figure it out if you understood what the `.get()` dictionary method does.

Comment: use more `print` to see exactly what you have **before** and **after** `degree[x] = degree.get(x, 0) + 1`

Comment: The problem is that you are adding 1 to the value so you get 1 greater than you expect. At point 3., `degree[x]` is 1. `degree.get(x, 0) + 1` gets the 1 and then adds one again, giving 2.

Comment: `degree.get(x, 0)` returns the current value associated with `x` in the dictionary or `0` if `x` isn't a key in the dictionary. Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)?

Comment: Thank you for all the input everyone- I have me added and moved the print statements as well as change values in the tuples and finally understand what is going on